# Remote Scan when updating using functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, execution-plan, linked-server

Why does using ISNULL() when updating through a linked server use Remote Scan to retrieve all rows and filter locally instead of filtering through Remote Query?

```
UPDATE LINKEDSERVER1.database1.dbo.table1 WITH(ROWLOCK)
SET number = ISNULL(number,0)
WHERE accounts = '123'

UPDATE LINKEDSERVER1.database1.dbo.table1 WITH(ROWLOCK)
SET number = number
WHERE accounts = '123'
```

The execution plan is as below:
[image: ExecutionPlan1]

The table does have a nonclustered unique index for the accounts column, but ISNULL() is not used on the accounts column and the index should still be usable. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I missing anything here?

Not really.  You are discovering that [distributed query processing](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event10/Distributed_Query_Deep_Dive) has lots of tricky limitations like this.

So the rule of thumb for using Linked Servers is to always use passthrough queries if you want remote execution.

```
exec (
'
UPDATE database1.dbo.table1 WITH(ROWLOCK)
SET number = ISNULL(number,0)
WHERE accounts = ''123''
'
) at LINKEDSERVER1
```

This is just a guess, it's likely that there's just not a transformation that will allow `ISNULL(number,0)` to be pushed across to the remote server.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure other than the difference in **execution plan** is enough for it to dumbly switch to a **Remote Scan** instead of **Remote Query** (maybe because of the order of events with the SET operator and using a function on the value being set, statistics or sargable related?).

What if you wrote the query like this instead, what does the execution plan show?

```
UPDATE LINKEDSERVER1.database1.dbo.table1 WITH(ROWLOCK)
SET number = 0
WHERE accounts = '123'
    AND number IS NULL
```

Another trick I've found to work in enforcing a **Remote Query** operator is first pulling the clustered index columns of the records that are needed to be updated into a local Temp Table, then joining to the remote table by that local Temp Table as part of the `UPDATE` to filter down the records instead and ensure a **Remote Query** occurs.

Example:

```
SELECT ClusteredIndexColumn
INTO #TempTable1
FROM LINKEDSERVER1.database1.dbo.table1 -- if you have a local copy of table1 here that'd be even better
WHERE accounts = '123'
    AND number IS NULL

UPDATE T1
SET number = 0
FROM LINKEDSERVER1.database1.dbo.table1 AS T1 WITH(ROWLOCK)
INNER JOIN #TempTable1 AS TT1
    ON T1.ClusteredIndexColumn = TT1.ClusteredIndexColumn
```